# How much disk space does Steam's content conversion save?

Tags: steam

Steam performed a "content conversion" on my game before starting it.  Does that save any disk space?  How much?

Comment: If you have an actual game you want to ask about, please specify.  Since the amount varies by game, we can't give a definitive answer without knowing which game.  As such, I've voted to close until you can add that information.

Comment: Fair enough.  Showing the values for 5 popular games would certainly be instructive.

Answer (score 4):

Valve are (slowly but surely) converting all of the games on Steam to use a more efficient format which will allow updates to be downloaded much quicker and use less bandwidth in doing so.  It does save space on your hard drive, but the amount varies per game.

Comment: Any idea how much? 0.01%? 1%?